# jQuery cycle plugin stopped working

Tags: jquery

Please can someone help as I am at my wits end! My website where the index page is on a jquery cycle plug in has stopped working. I thought it was because i was using 1.7 but upgraded to 1.9 and also added the migration data to make it work but whatever I try nothing works! My website is:
http://nailandrockett.com
Does anyone have ANY suggestions that could help? I did this website a year or so ago and I have not done one since so I am a it rusty and cannot find a simple answer anywhere? I am cannot figure out what I need to do to get it to work??

Thanks in advance

Tina

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin is downloaded directly from github.
Now link http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js is not loaded, 403 is returned.

Consider moving plugin to your site or get correct link